# fractional encoder in SEAL library?

Tags: cryptography, seal

In the newer version of the SEAL library, I am not able to find out the fractional encoder. Is that present in the library and I am missing or it has been removed ??

Answer (score 0):

The `FractionalEncoder` was removed as its performance was relatively poor, and its correctness behavior was hard to understand. Since SEAL 3.0 the CKKS encryption scheme is providing a much better way of computing on rational, real, and complex numbers.